# USB drive becomes write protected after inserting it

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, write-protect

Whenever I insert a USB drive in my desktop PC running Windows 7 Ultimate, it becomes write protected. Then when I use it on my laptop, I can't delete the files on it.

I already tried scanning for malware and viruses.

Can I repair this, eventually without reformatting?

Comment: I dont know what to do. I tried scanning, there is no virus. no malwares.

Comment: I mean, you said you searched on Google and "followed what they said". So by that, you meant a virus scan?

Comment: What i search was also to repair the usb from not being write protected.

Comment: Are you saying you *can* format the drive to make it writeable again? If not, then please see [this](http://superuser.com/questions/402688/why-did-my-flash-drive-become-read-only-and-how-can-i-fix-it)... the drive may be a lost cause. In any case, copy *all* the data off the drive **now**.

Comment: So I need to reformat my desktop PC?

Comment: @user1302274 I was referring to formatting the flash (USB) drive...

Comment: I cant reformat it either.

Comment: @user1302274 Then you have likely run into a similar issue as me. I've personally accepted that that drive will never work again; there seems to be nothing to do short of a firmware flash (and frankly, a new drive is easier).

Comment: it was a new flash drive :( I think the problem was with the desktop pc. cause all the usb drives being inserted in it is being write protected.

Comment: Which medium did you try scanning? How exactly is it write protected?

Comment: @TomWijsman what do you mean by medium. I scan my desktop pc. but no virus. I was write protected cause i cant copy anything from it. and cant delete files saying its write protected.

Comment: Is **ReadyBoost** turned on? Because I think that can cause it to be locked. But honestly it sounds like a faulty contact.

Answer (score 1):

This either happens by the hardware lock or a software setting:

1. **You have write protected the USB drive by sliding a lock.**

   To resolve this, you can slide it back to be unlocked. Use tape if you accidentally lock it.
2. **Your storage device policy is set to be write protected.**

   To resolve this, open up the registry editor (Start -> Run -> `regedit`) and browse to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies`, there you can create / edit a new DWORD called `WriteProtect` and set the value to `0`.

   If `StorageDevicePolicies` doesn't exist, you can safely create that registry key as well.

Check the latter on both your desktop and laptop.

Comment: Have tried it. But, for example. from my laptop I copy a file in my usb. then in my desktop pc, it became corrupted when I access it. I think the prob is in my desktop.

Comment: @user1302274: Sounds like you are not doing safe removal?

Comment: Im doing safe removal.

Comment: This fixed my issue on a domain based organization.

Answer (score 1):

If the flash drive is especially old or sees *heavy* use, there's a chance that it's on its last legs and the flash controller can no longer (safely) write to the memory blocks. If that's the case, copy everything off of the drive to a safe location *as soon as possible*.

(Note: I'm not familiar with how operating systems actually handle this scenario, as I've yet to experience it myself. I'm just throwing out the possibility.)

EDIT: Sorry Bob, I didn't see your reply to the question before I posted this.

Answer (score 1):

If there's nothing physically wrong with the drive
this could help anyone looking at this thread.

From an Administrator cmd prompt (Win+X, A):

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk X (Replace "X" with the number of your write-protected hard drive.)
attributes disk clear readonly
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert USB drive

- go to Computer
- Right click the USB Drive icon and click Properties
- Click the security tab.
- Click edit under the Group or user names display.
- Click on Everyone (so that it is highlighted) then below in the
  permissions for Everyone area, tick Full Control.

Answer (score 0):

Open up a console (cmd.exe) and type `diskpart`. Type `list disk` then `select disk 0` (change the `0` to whatever number your USB drive is. Type `detail disk` and check the "Current Read-only State" and the "Read-only" attributes. If it says "No" for the first and "Yes" for the second, your USB drive may be going bad. If it's the other way around, then it's a policy/program messing with it. If this is the case, back up your files on the USB drive, open up another console and type (again, replace the 0 on `select disk 0` with your USB drive number):

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk 0
clean
create partition primary
format fs=FAT32 quick
```

Safely remove the USB drive and try it again.

Answer (score -2):

Works except in windows 7.

1. Right-click the USB drive icon then select **Properties**.
2. Go to **Sharing** > **Advanced sharing**.
3. Tick **Share this folder**
4. Click **Permissions**.
5. Select **Everyone**.
6. Check **Allow** under **Full Control**.
7. Click **Apply** > **Apply** > **Close**.