# Can't "run" files from microSD card on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, freeze, sd-card

I have a microSD card. When I put it into my Windows 7 machine using a USB adaptor, Windows Explorer shows it and I also can open it and see the files and folders. But I can't run the files and open the folders. When I double click on any of them, Windows hangs. I can't even format it because format fails. I also tried to recover its data using some tools but that didn't success either. I also tried the scan and fix pop-up.

I don't think it's dead but surely there is a problem with it. And also there isn't any switch on the card reader or micro sd card.
Is there any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Does it work as desired on another machine?

Comment: What is the condition of the card reader? Is it of good quality?

Comment: @Dave: No, I also tried to test it with phones but it doesn't work as desired.

Comment: @Firee: The card reader doesn't have any problem. I have tested that reader by many micro SD cards before.

Comment: I think it be broke !!

Comment: No fixing way for that in this a full of professionals forum!?

Comment: No any solution!?

Comment: Have you tried doing `chkdsk /f` on the card?

Comment: Yeah, it was the first work I did on that card!

Comment: [Recover Data from Card that cannnot be read](http://superuser.com/q/855876/364367), [Fix SD card that cannot be formatted](http://superuser.com/q/854588/364367), [Why did my flash drive become “read only” and (how) can I fix it?](http://superuser.com/q/402688/364367)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem about your micros SD card now , you can copy all information to a new SD card , and use the new one instead of the old one . I think that is the best way to solve your problem .

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  You probably didn't notice that this is a really old question.  The problem for the author has long since been overtaken by events.  So any new answer is really for the benefit of other people with a similar problem.  What you posted was probably reasonable advice for this particular case, but it's only one possibility and is based on opinion rather than hard diagnostics.  For a new answer to be useful at this point, it should really cover a broader range of possibilities, and provide more complete guidance on how to assess the best solution.

Comment: Please explain how you can copy the data from a card that cannot be read.

Comment: I am sorry I met the most similar problem to the original poster , but i did not meet the problem about windows hangs , i just can not run the files , so I use my way to solve it , that is  OK .