# How to access a read protected SD card?

Tags: sd-card, reverse-engineer

EDIT: please note unlike this question [Fix SD card that cannot be formatted](https://superuser.com/questions/854588/fix-sd-card-that-cannot-be-formatted)

I for 1 have READ protection, not WRITE protection
also, I dont want to format the card, i want to retrieve data from it. My question is very different

I'm trying to read the SD card that came with my Pioneer radio so I can hack the firmware. However I think Pioneer has read protection on the SD card. See some screenshots here

[image: Img1]

[image: Img2]

I tried using the permission options in Windows but no luck

Looking like I have to first circumvent the read protection before I use  tools to get the files. Any idea how? I can use Linux if needed

Comment: If it's disk 2, it has a problem, wrong capacity.

Comment: Put a Live Linux on an USB stick and boot on that. Check what `fdisk`, `gparted` or similar tool shows about the SD. If that's something the radio needs to work, I'd probably try cloning it with Clonezilla or similar first (something that can do bit by bit clone), and see if I can get access to the clone.

Comment: Thanks @Peregrino69 I'll boot into Linux and see what those tools tell me. I'll see if Clonezilla will ignore the read protection

Comment: I don't think such "read protection" really exists. The card probably contains some file system or something Windows simply doesn't understand, or it might be somehow encrypted. A tool that can do bitwise cloning should create one on one carbon copy of the media, whatever it is.

Comment: ok, let me try Clonezilla

Comment: I voted to reopen, but I agree with @Peregrino69 - it's unlikely 'read protected' it's just Windows doesn't have the faintest idea what it is. The Pioneer could be programmed to 'know' the format, so the entire header section/MBR/filetable of the drive could be missing & it wouldn't care.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. Yes I tried a tool to guess the file system but the drive wouldn't show up in it. Not sure what tools in linux i can use