# Raspberry pi sd card recovery

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, sd-card

Yesterday my pi started to behave different (web server, ssh didn't work) so I unplugged and then plugged it however it did not boot. Then my plan was to back up the sd card flash a rasbian image then put the backup in.

I see two partitions on the sd card, boot and rootfs. The rootfs part only has empty `home srv log` and `tmp` folder. Please tell me if there is any way to recover my data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recover Data from Card that cannnot be read](https://superuser.com/questions/855876/recover-data-from-card-that-cannnot-be-read)

Answer (score 0):

To backup your raspberry pi, you should always backup the whole image from which you are able to boot. Have a look at this link: https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/back-up-raspberry-pi/