# I am unable to open or format my 8gb memory card may be because of read only file

Tags: windows-8.1

I brought sandisk 8 gb memory card but it is not opening and even if I try to format it it does not format may be because of read only How can I change it or what should I have to do to fix this problem.. HELP

Comment: what type of memory card have you bought (SD..)? Do you receive error message or just nothing happens? Have you tried it in different pc / card reader?

Comment: If it is an SDcard, did you make sure that the write protect switch is off?

Comment: Ensure the write protect switch is off as mentioned above, and try to repartition and reformat (you can also try to reformat via Linux or even Android which sometimes helps), but if the hardware is faulty obviously none of this will accomplish anything. If the card is new get it replaced (fakes are quite common, especially if you bought it extra cheap online from anyone other than an authorised SanDisk dealer), otherwise buy a new one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why did my flash drive become "read only" and (how) can I fix it?](http://superuser.com/questions/402688/why-did-my-flash-drive-become-read-only-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

When contents of the filesystem is giving you problems, the fix is easy: Instead of working with the filesystem, get rid of the filesystem.

What this means is: Delete the partition, and make a new one. Any partition manager will do. I do not know about windows 8.1 specifically, but earlier windows versions have a partitioning tool located under disk management.

Delete the partition (make sure you're doing it on the right disk!), ensure that the changes are written, and then create a new one. When asked, the filesystem type you want is most likely exFAT.

Comment: Emphasis on MAKE SURE YOU'RE DELETING THE CORRECT PARTITION!!!

Comment: Good advice, but unfortunately getting rid of the filesystem is hardly a catch-all solution, especially with cheap/fake flash devices which often exhibit read-only type behaviour when they inevitably fail.